# passing an copy of arraylist to avoid concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I have below java piece of code that throws `ConcurrentModificationException` below is the java piece of code

below is the lists that are being declared

```
List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItems= new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
            brokerInvoiceLineItems=brokerInvoice.getLineItems();
```

below is the the piece of code that is throwing concurrentmodification exception

```
if (brokerInvoiceLineItems == null) {
    brokerInvoiceLineItems = brokerInvoiceHome.findLineitemsByInvoiceId(brokerInvoice.getId());
}
for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem : brokerInvoiceLineItems) {
    if (fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend(brokerInvoiceLineItem)) {
        if (!isAnyValid)
            isAnyValid = true;
    }
}
```

now the issue is that if brokerInvoiceLineItems is not null then for the first iteration it goes inside the loop and the value is set true of variable named isAnyValid but as soon the first iteration is over then for the second iteration it goesagain to the line `for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem : brokerInvoiceLineItems){` and then it does not go the next line it throws concurrent modification exeption

so this means it must be modifying brokerInvoiceLineItems size while iterating through it. This is probably occurring in `fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend` so i am consider making a copy of brokerInvoiceLineItems and modifying the copy instead. so please advise how can i pass the copy to `fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend(brokerInvoiceLineItem)`

Also please advise how to use copyonwriteArray list also to avoid such error

Comment: how about using, Collections.unmodifiableList(brokerInvoiceLineItems);

Comment: Can you post your `brokerInvoice.getLineItems` and `brokerInvoiceHome.findLineitemsByInvoiceId` methods?

Answer (score 1):

I think you get this exception when you remove some items of `brokerInvoiceLineItems`.

To avoid this exception, use an iterator

```
Iterator<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> iterator = brokerInvoiceLineItems.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem = iterator.next();
    // your code
}
```

instead of

`for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem : brokerInvoiceLineItems) {`

so your code is:

```
Iterator<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> iterator = brokerInvoiceLineItems.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem = iterator.next();
  if (fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend(brokerInvoiceLineItem)) {
    if (!isAnyValid)
      isAnyValid = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: so can you please convert my above piece of code and show me specially for the for loop part please

Comment: I did. Just replace the for loop with the first code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new ArrayList and add to it all the elements of your previous ArrayList object.

```
ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> otherList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
otherList.addAll(brokerInvoiceLineItems);
```

Note: if you change your for statement for another like:

```
for(int i=0;i<brokerInvoiceLineItems.size();i++){
```

You'll not get that ConcurrentModificationException.

Update: example code:

```
if (brokerInvoiceLineItems == null) {
    brokerInvoiceLineItems = brokerInvoiceHome.findLineitemsByInvoiceId(brokerInvoice.getId());
}

ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> otherList = new ArrayList<BrokerInvoiceLineItem>();
otherList.addAll(brokerInvoiceLineItems);

for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem : brokerInvoiceLineItems) {
    if (fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend(otherList)) {
        if (!isAnyValid)
            isAnyValid = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: then what about this next statement if (fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend(brokerInvoiceLineItem)) { how i will overcome from this

Comment: I suppose you are adding or removing items from the list on that method. A good practice is not modifying lists while you are iterating over them, so the first approach (copying your list to another) would be better.

Comment: Thanks request you to please make changes in my abve piece of code so that i can grasp more

Answer (score 0):

I'm assumming that you are modifying the `brokerInvoiceLineItems` in the method `fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend`. You can use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)
 instead of the ArrayList. This allows you to iterate the list and at the same time update it. There is some cost to this since it creates a new array everytime you add something to it. A sample code would look like this:

```
    // Member field declaration
    List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> brokerInvoiceLineItems;

    // Retrieve the list of objects
    List<BrokerInvoiceLineItem> items = brokerInvoice.getLineItems();
    if (items == null) {
        items = brokerInvoiceHome.findLineitemsByInvoiceId(brokerInvoice.getId());
    }

    // Initialize your member variable to be a 
    // CopyOnWriteArrayList with the above elements
    brokerInvoiceLineItems = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(items);

    // Iterate over the elements and possibly update the list from
    // the fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend method
    for (BrokerInvoiceLineItem brokerInvoiceLineItem : brokerInvoiceLineItems) {
        if (fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend(brokerInvoiceLineItem)) {
            if (!isAnyValid)
                isAnyValid = true;
        }
    }
```

My code assumes that you have a class which stores a list of BrokerInvoiceLineItem and it's initialization is made in the constructor.

Usually it's a bad idea to iterate over a list and call another method which updates it. You can use an iterator to traverse it and remove certain elements. Your `fetchNewAndOldCFandAmend` maybe can be used to indicate if the current item should be removed from the list and call the iterator's remove method.

Comment: please advise how we will use this , if possible can you please show it in my above piece of code that will be a great help

Comment: Can you add more details about how this class is used and how is the list retrieved from the two brokerInvoice objects? It's a new copy of existing elements or the underlying List used by them?